# Android: Determine speed in x and y direction using sensors

Tags: android, sensors

I want to measure the speed of the movement between two points which are close to eachother. Lets say 50 cm. It's not possible to do this with gps.

I tried using accelerometer and the following formula:
V = a*t(initial speed is always 0).

But this gave me weird results.

What is the best way to do this? What is the output of the accelerometer anyways? m/s2?